# Can you use an optional argument in a rust macro without syntax variables?

Tags: rust, macros

Using an optional argument inside a rust macro `$(...)?` I'd like to be able to change how a struct is formulated. For example:

```rs
struct Field<T>(T);
struct OptionalField<T>(T);

define_struct!(StructName => {
  field_one: i32,
  field_two?: i32
});

// would ideally evaluate to

struct StructName {
  field_one: Field<i32>,
  field_two: OptionalField<i32>
}
```

Writing a macro with repeated sections isn't the difficult part however, the part that's giving me trouble is how I can make the optional question mark change the type used as the struct's field type. So far I've tried this:

```rs
macro_rules! define_struct {
    ($name:ident => {
        $($field_name:ident$(?)?: $type:ty),*
    }) => {
        struct $name {
            $($field_name: $(Optional)?Field<$type>),*
        }
    };
}
```

The macro invocation is fine and follows the defined pattern however inserting the `Optional` before the `Field` identifier is what's proving difficult. The section `$(Optional)?` throws the error:

```
attempted to repeat an expression containing no syntax variables matched as repeating at this depth
|
|  $($field_name: $(Optional)?Field<$type>),*
|                  ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Is there any way to insert a keyword depending upon the presence of an optional macro pattern without having to use a syntax variable?

Comment: I'm not aware of a way to do this with `macro_rules`. It would however be fairly easy to implement this using proc macros.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it with an [incremental `tt` muncher](https://veykril.github.io/tlborm/decl-macros/patterns/tt-muncher.html) and [push-down accumulation](https://veykril.github.io/tlborm/decl-macros/patterns/push-down-acc.html):

```
macro_rules! define_struct {
    (@fields $name:ident { $($fields:tt)* } $field_name:ident?: $type:ty, $($rest:tt)*) => {
        define_struct!(@fields
            $name {
                $($fields)*
                $field_name: OptionalField<$type>,
            }
            $($rest)*);
    };
    (@fields $name:ident { $($fields:tt)* } $field_name:ident: $type:ty, $($rest:tt)*) => {
        define_struct!(@fields
            $name {
                $($fields)*
                $field_name: Field<$type>,
            }
            $($rest)*);
    };
    (@fields $name:ident { $($fields:tt)* }) => {
        struct $name { $($fields)* }
    };
    
    ($name:ident => { $($fields:tt)* }) => {
        define_struct!(@fields $name {} $($fields)*);
    };
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=9fe867b378aa727b6b833c7568a75046)